# how to iterate items of list in columns of dataframe

Tags: pandas, loops, conditional-statements

Here is my dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'animal':['dog','cat','rabbit','pig'],'color':['red','green','blue','purple'],\
               'season':['spring,','summer','fall','winter']})
```

and I have a list

```
l = ['dog','green','purple']
```

with these dataframe and list, I wanna add another column to df, which is actually a result if column 'animal' or column 'color' matched some item of  l(list).

so, the result(dataframe) I want is below(I wanna express a table):

```
pd.DataFrame({'animal':['dog','cat','rabbit','pig'],
               'color':['red','green','blue','purple'],
               'season':['spring,','summer','fall','winter'],
               'tar_rm':[1,1,0,1] })
```

Do I have to iterate list in each rows of column?
I believe one of pandas' advantage is broadcasting but i'm not sure it's possible here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
cols = ['animal','color']
df['tar_rm'] = df[cols].isin(l).any(axis=1).astype(int)
print (df)
   animal   color  season  tar_rm
0     dog     red  spring       1
1     cat   green  summer       1
2  rabbit    blue    fall       0
3     pig  purple  winter       1
```

**Details**:

First compare filtered columns of `DataFrame` by [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
print (df[cols].isin(l))
   animal  color 
0    True  False  
1   False   True  
2   False  False   
3   False   True
```

Then test if at least one `True` per rows by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print (df[cols].isin(l).any(axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

An last cast boolean to integers:

```
print (df[cols].isin(l).any(axis=1).astype(int))
0    1
1    1
2    0
3    1
dtype: int32
```

If performance is important compare by `isin` each column separately, convert to numpy array, chain by bitwise OR and last cast to integers:

```
df['tar_rm'] = (df['animal'].isin(l).values | df['color'].isin(l).values).astype(int)
```

**Performance**: Depends of number of tows, number of matched rows and number of values of list, so best test in real data:

```
l = ['dog','green','purple']

df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True).sample(1)
In [173]: %timeit df['tar_rm'] = df[['animal','color']].isin(l).any(axis=1).astype(int)
2.11 ms ± 250 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [174]: %timeit df['tar_rm'] = (df['animal'].isin(l).values | df['color'].isin(l).values).astype(int)
487 µs ± 9.87 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [175]: %timeit df['tar_rm'] = np.where(df['animal'].isin(l) | df['color'].isin(l), 1, 0)
805 µs ± 15.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

using `numpy`

```
df['tar_rm'] = np.where(df['animal'].isin(l) | df['color'].isin(l), 1, 0)
```

Output

```
   animal   color   season  tar_rm
0     dog     red  spring,       1
1     cat   green   summer       1
2  rabbit    blue     fall       0
3     pig  purple   winter       1
```